# Entity framework - virtual table for multiple entities (code first)

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, code-first

We are building a Context with multiple entities. All entities build on a abstract class with ID (guid).

We want all entities to have relation to a common Log table, however can't get EFCF to understand the relationship due to the naming.

```
public class Log {
  public BaseEntity Entity {get;set;}
  public Guid EntityID {get;set;}
}

public class Example : BaseEntity {
  public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs {get;set;}
}
```

Can anyone help on a pattern which support? We've tried abstracting, setting up the OnModelCreating etc. but keep getting fuzzy errors due to the none-supported naming. If we add these;

```
[ForeignKey("EntityID")]
public Example Example {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("EntityID")]
public Example5 Example5 {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("EntityID")]
public Example2 Example2 {get;set;}
```

set of properties on the Log class, everything works fine. Problem occurs when adding a new Log entry.

Comment: What do you do when you create the Log?  Did you try casting it as a BaseEntity? And perhaps a type value so you can manually recast back to your type?

Comment: Or you can make it just be a getter based on the GUID?

Comment: Think logically. Can you make such FK in relational database?

Answer (score 0):

I would a possible and working solution, abstracting the common fields into a base class.

Using the MapInheritedProperties() in the model building (and followed)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Example>().Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());

modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Log>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.BaseEntity)
    .WithMany(x => x.Logs)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.ToTable("Example");
        x.MapKey(new[] { "ID" });
    })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I can now assign the "virtual" table to any entity, as long as they derive from the base class.